# trying to use local storage to get value JS

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to make a 'welcome, abby'  by clicking submit button but using local storage. Also, it shouldn't be 'welcome, '. it turns out keep refresh after i click the button

```
<p>
<label for="inName" >What is your name?</label>
<input type="text" id="inName" name="f_name"/>
    </p>

<!-- GET COLOUR-->
<p>
<label for="inColor" >What is your favourite colour? </label>
<input type="color" id="inColor" name="f_color" />
</p>
        
<p>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Click to save" />
    </p>
```

js

```
var name=document.getElementById("inName");
var backColor=document.getElementById("inColor");
var btn=document.getElementById("submit");
var btndel=document.getElementById("btnDel");

btn.onsubmit=getData;
btndel.onclick=deleteData;

function getData(){
    var temp={
        Name:name.value,
        bckcolor:backColor.value
    }
   
   localStorage.setItem("temp", JSON.stringify(temp));
    
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("temp"));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`onsubmit` is a `<form>` event, not `<input>`event.

moreover, if you call both `onclick` and `onsubmit`, `onclick` fires before `onsubmit`, so you delete data before you get.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to perform the variable assignment operation after the function, like so

```
function getData(){
    var temp={
        Name:name.value,
        bckcolor:backColor.value
    }
   
   localStorage.setItem("temp", JSON.stringify(temp));
    
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("temp"));

}
btn.onsubmit = getData;
```

and try it again. JavaScript is executed from the top of the file, to the bottom, so when it reads `btn.onsubmit=getData;`, it looks above it and says 'I don't see a variable declared called getData, it doesn't exist.' There's many other ways to execute this, of course, but I think that is what you're trying to do. I also do not see the `deleteData` variable declared anywhere.

Comment: i did have the button onsubmit, but still not working.

Comment: function declarations in Javascript are 'hoisted', so you can call them before their declaration

Comment: That's right, I forgot JavaScript was like that.